# How to recognize a multiple Vuforia AR targets in Unity without creating a separate object for each?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to do a simple AR app using [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) and [Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com).

I have a large number of AR targets in the Vuforia database, and my goal is that each of them be recognized by the AR camera and the target name was displayed on the screen (to understand which one was recognized).

I'm new to development in Unity, so now I've made only an application in which all the targets are located in one scene as [ImageTargets](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Image-Target-Guide) and on top of them are the objects that are displayed when recognised. I want to increase the number of targets, but creating separate objects for all of them inside the scene looks wrong.

Is there a way to add a large number of targets to the scene without creating them all manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one game object per image target is the right way to do it. If you don't want to start with lots of complex objects in the scene, you can instantiate the targets' content dynamically using prefabs and tracking events instead of objects on top of them.

More details here: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Working-with-Vuforia-and-Unity.html